# URLs in list become outdated when adjusting file name in site-content

Tags: list, document-library, url, content, rename

I have a list on my SharePoint site containing URLs to the contents of the site, namely URLs to files in a directory within `Documents`.

So something like

```
Documents
  |- subdirectory
    |- file_a.pdf
    |- file_b.pdf
    |- etc.
```

Now I changed the name of `subdirectory` into `1. subdirectory` for the sake of archiving - and therefore, all the URLs pointing towards those pdf files became outdated in my list (since the URLs still point towards the initial directory name `subdirectory` instead of `1. subdirectory`.

Is there a way to update all URLs at once in this list? Or do I have to adjust every item in the list one by one? I'm talking about hundreds of PDFs...

Best,
Stefan

Comment: As per my understanding there is no direct way / OOTB way to do it. You can prepare some Power Shell script to update URL accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to enable the **Document ID Service** which is a site collection feature. With this feature, a unique identifier will be assigned to a document with a permanent link. So, if you move or rename a parent folder, the link will stay the same and not be impacted.

Unfortunately, in your case, without this feature activated before the *disaster*, you have to change everything. Build a tool in PowerShell for example to automate the process.

Source: [Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)

Comment: Thank you @jleture. However, I do not have any admin-rights to SharePoint and I just manage a dedicated site. Or could we enable unique Document IDs per site?

Comment: Do you have access to site settings? Document ID is a site collection feature.